# Google Analytics segmentation customvar vs uri

Tags: google-analytics

I want to be able segment analytics data by company once my customers have logged into my website. Being very new to analytics, it seems like there is a couple of ways I could do this.

1. Set a visitor level custom variable that would signify the company. For instance, _setCustomVar(1, 'customer', 'ABC Corp', 1)
2. Pass in a custom Url to my _trackPageview calls whose first segment would signify the company. For instance, _trackPageview('/ABCCorp/the rest of the document path, querystring, etc.')

It seems you can't filter on a custom variable so I could not create a view\profile for each company but I could use Segments and Custom Reports off an 'All Web Site Data' view to do that instead.

Going the custom url route seems to be more flexible since I could either filter or use segments.

Are there any other pitfalls or reasons to suggest using one of these two approaches over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use case is better suited for custom variables.

Changing the URL will make it more difficult to do things like "How many home page views did I get" or "What do clients usually do after they login".

Also, you can create custom reports based on the information you're passing back and include the custom variable information as the first key. Pretty easy to duplicate GA's current top reports in a custom report using the custom variable as the main dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Tom that CustomVar is a much better and cleaner solution.

You might want to switch to new Universal Analytics and use [Custom Dimenions instead](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets). It's even better and you can set up property filters with Custom Dimenions too, so this should cover all your needs.